# Emacs symbol-at-point with C++ scope

Tags: emacs, namespaces, scope, point, symbols

Has anyone extended `symbol-at-point` to include, in my use case the C++ namespace, scope as well?

Having the cursor on `std::vector` should preferably return `("std" "vector")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CEDET` toolset includes a set of local context parsers that will do what you want, but it doesn't extend `symbol-at-point`.  Instead it has its own context parser.  If you have a version of Emacs with CEDET pre-installed, just enabled `semantic-mode`, and then use the command `semantic-analyze-current-context`.  It will return a class with the prefix.  If you just want the raw prefix for a program, then you can instead use `semantic-ctxt-current-symbol` to return whatever is under point.